# Doxygen 1.9.3: Undocumented external namespaces from .tags files are shown in my Namespace index

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces, doxygen

After some bug squashing I've gotten my first Doxygen setup to build correctly and am now in the process of fixing visual issues with the documentation.

Right off the bat one problem I'm having is that the documentation shows namespaces from external tag files (Qt documentation) within the Namespace view as if they were my own namespaces. They appear without a hyperlink and no description, and I definitely did not add documentation for them myself, nor add members to them in code:

[image: Namespace list with errant external namespaces]

The only namespace in that list that is from my library is "Qx".

In case it's relevant, the tags I'm using specifically are from Qt 6.2.3:

- qtconcurrent/qtconcurrent.tags
- qtcore/qtcore.tags
- qtgui/qtgui.tags
- qtnetwork/qtnetwork.tags
- qtsql/qtsql.tags
- qtwidgets/qtwidgets.tags
- qtxml/qtxml.tags

I would be surprised if this is intended behavior since I didn't document those namespaces and don't want them in this list since this is documentation for my library and not Qt.

Is this a bug? It could be a regression of [#5258](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5258), but I'm not sure these namespaces are nested.

Regardless, is there a way I can prevent these external namespaces from being show in this list since it gives the false impression that they belong to my project? If they're mentioned elsewhere explicitly in my documentation I'd of course still like them to be linked to (despite that being unlikely for these in particular).

Here are my Doxyfile options (generated via CMake):

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.3 (c0b9eafbfb53286ce31e75e2b6c976ee4d345473)
PROJECT_NAME           = Qx
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 0.1.0.0
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/build-Qx-Desktop_Qt_6_2_3_MSVC2022_64bit_Static/doc
REPEAT_BRIEF           = NO
ALIASES                = "qflag{2}=@typedef \1^^<p>The \1 type is a typedef for QFlags\<\2\>. It stores an OR combination of \2 values.</p>"
WARN_AS_ERROR          = YES
INPUT                  = C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/doc/global.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/doc/mainpage.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/doc/namespace.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/core/doc/core.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/core/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/core/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/gui/doc/gui.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/gui/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/gui/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/io/doc/io.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/io/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/io/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/utility/doc/utility.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/utility/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/utility/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/network/doc/network.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/network/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/network/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/widgets/doc/widgets.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/widgets/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/widgets/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/xml/doc/xml.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/xml/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/xml/include \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/windows/doc/windows.dox \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/windows/src \
                         C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/windows/include
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */.git/* \
                         */.svn/* \
                         */.hg/* \
                         */CMakeFiles/* \
                         */_CPack_Packages/* \
                         DartConfiguration.tcl \
                         CMakeLists.txt \
                         CMakeCache.txt
EXAMPLE_PATH           = C:/Users/Chris/Engineering/Development/Qt/6.2.3/Qx/comp/core/doc/snippets
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = "Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(flagsType,enumType)=typedef QFlags<enumType> flagsType;"
TAGFILES               = C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtconcurrent/qtconcurrent.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ \
                         C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtcore/qtcore.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ \
                         C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtgui/qtgui.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ \
                         C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtnetwork/qtnetwork.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ \
                         C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtsql/qtsql.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ \
                         C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtwidgets/qtwidgets.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/ \
                         C:/Engineering/Development/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.3/qtxml/qtxml.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES

DOT_PATH               = C:\Engineering\Utilities\Graphviz\bin
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Furthermore don't show the complete settings file, but just the changes comp[ared to the default settings (i.e. the results of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

Comment: @albert I've updated the post. Woops on the version, definitely important (it's 1.9.3) and thanks for pointing out the '-x' switch. Very useful.

Comment: An issue has been created: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9241